# In the context of an vector declaration how does y downto x work when x > 0?

Tags: vhdl

I am hoping someone can explain what exactly downto is doing for a

```
y downto x

where y > x > 0
```

From my reading x is supposed to be the LSB

**Example**:

```
constant FOO            : std_logic_vector( 5 downto  0)   := x"F";           

  constant BAR             : std_logic_vector( 11 downto  0)   := x"6

  constant BAZ            : std_logic_vector(16 downto 12)   := x"0";
```

What exactly is the “downto” doing in this context? Why would somebody want to do 16 downto 12 instead of 4 downto 0?

How does the hardware generation look different? Is there wasted space on BAZ from 11->0 if not where is it allocated?

I am reviewing a very large project, so I am assuming they had a reason to define it this way?

Comment: It won't affect the hardware. It is just indices used in your HDL code, that for convenience you can have them starting at different numbers.

Comment: If you want to make this an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: For example, somewhere else in the code, there could be something like adr <= BAZ & BAR; where adr is a std_logic_vector(16 downto 0). It is nice (but not necessary) to have the BAZ vector indexes lining up with the adr vector indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It's used for slicing larger words, we need to do that all the time.

For instance, if you were coding a floating point unit, you might have the following declarations (this is not a valid IEEE754 real, nor is it valid VHDL!)

variable real_num is array(31 downto 0) of std_logic_vector
exponent := real_num(31 downto 24)
mantissa := real_num(23 downto 0)

Exponent could have been declared as either (31 downto 24) or (7 downto 0), and each have their advantages, each will result in 8 bits being assigned, but will be labelled differently in the debug screen. As long that you index them consistently when you slice and concatenate, everything will work.

Comment: My constants are defined as a vector, but they are not slicing and existing vector. Does your answer still apply?